# Using Excel Power Query to create new columns based on indentation of text

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query, indentation

What I am trying to achieve I think is best explained with some pictures.

I have the following example data set (raw data):

[image: Raw Data]

Using column1 I need to create two columns, the first will contain the text from the non indented rows and the other will contain the text from the indented rows, like so (After Power Query):

[image: After Power Query]

I need to transform column1 using Power Query to create 2 new columns. The first with the rows that are not indented, and the second with the rows that are indented.

Is this possible using Power Query.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Column2 can be made with a `custom column` under `Add Column` with the following function:

```
= if Text.StartsWith([Column1]," ") then null else [Column1]
```

Then use the `fill` option under `transform` to fill the rows with the addresses

Column3 can be made with:

```
= if Text.StartsWith([Column1]," ") then [column1] else null
```

Comment: This is working great except the fill option does nothing on the address column.

Comment: Replace "" with null, I just learned that it does not see "" as an empty cell.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!